# Users value change in GA query explorer depending on number of metrics/dimensions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics, analytics

I am using https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ to export data from analytics for my customers.

I export regularly data from it based on few metrics and few dimensions (users, newusers, sessions, bounceRate, sessionDuration as metrics and fullReferrer, campaign, source, medium, adcontent, devicecategory and dateHour as dimensions).

When I export this data for a day X I get a value for users (let's say 52000) but if I do another export with users I get a different value (like 41000).
Why do I have such a big difference?

Also, when checking the data in GA, the value is the same as export with users only (41000).

Why adding more metric/dimensions would change the value of another metric?

Answer (score 0):

Users is a strange metric.

- It's very calculation intensive, so likely to induce sampling.
- There are actually two different ways of calculating it, which may achieve slightly different results (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042)
- It's not additive - 10 users per day for 3 days could be anywhere between 10 and 30 total users.
- Due to a bug, Google Analytics will give you an incorrect totals on exported reports (it adds up the values which, as we know, is not correct).

I suspect that your issue here is caused by the last two points, but you should also bear the first two in mind.